# iOS Simulator launch fails when specifying each flavor a different $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

Tags: dart, flutter

After configuring multiple flavors for my flutter app, compiling and installing to iOS Simulator succeeds. But the final step of launching the app fails with the following error:
`$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)" is unknown to FrontBoard`
Each .xcconfig file for the flavor has the following entry with unique bundle identifier.
`PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=Flavor`

Seems like compile time PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER is resolved successfully but somehow launching procedure fails.

Hardcoding the bundle identifier to the project also does not work well, the first bundle identifier is always used to launch the app.

The project is configured as below:
[image: Project]

```
ProcessException: Process "/usr/bin/xcrun" exited abnormally:
$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER): -1

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application
"$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)" is unknown to FrontBoard").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)" is unknown to
    FrontBoard.
    Application "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)" is unknown to FrontBoard.
  Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 000D67C7-91CE-48E4-A73B-93E69F888255
  $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points
  --observatory-port=0
Error launching application on iPhone Xs.
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this github issue

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15567

Comment: Yes thanks, it seems like it is same as my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting the scheme, and letting XCode remake another one.